# SqlClient count by date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I couldn't articulate my question to google to find out how to do this and i hope someone will help me.

Here is my starting point.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT BOOK_ID, BOOK_DATE, Sum(BOOK_COUNT) " +
                                    "FROM BOOKS " +
                                    "WHERE (BOOK_ID = '1' OR " +
                                           "BOOK_ID = '2' OR " +
                                           "BOOK_ID = '3' )  " +
                                    "AND STATUS  = '0'    " +
                                    "GROUP BY BOOK_ID, BOOK_DATE ", cn);

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    int id = (int)reader[0]; 
    DateTime date = (DateTime)reader[1]; 
    int count = (int)reader[2];

    if (id == 1)
    {
       /*...*/
    }

    if (id == 2)
    {
       /*...*/
    }

    if (id == 3)
    {
       /*...*/
    }
 }

 reader.Close();
```

DBSCA

[image: DBSCA]

I would like to sort by date and if the date and id is the same, then get count of books...
Like this:

```
BOOK_DATE  BOOK_ID  BOOK_COUNT  
2014.11.17     1        1         
2014.11.21     2        1           
2014.11.25     2        2           
2014.11.26     1        2           
2014.11.26     3        2           
2014.11.27     3        1           
2014.11.28     3        1
```

Thanks if anyone can help me, and I apologize for bad English!

Comment: FYI shorter notation `WHERE BOOK_ID IN (1,2,3) ...`

Comment: If the `BOOK_ID` is a numerical datatype (it should be!), then you should not add unnecessary single quotes around it in your `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group by` the date portion of the date time field:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT BOOK_ID, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, BOOK_DATE)), Sum(BOOK_COUNT) " +
                                    "FROM BOOKS " +
                                    "WHERE (BOOK_ID = '1' OR " +
                                           "BOOK_ID = '2' OR " +
                                           "BOOK_ID = '3' )  " +
                                    "AND STATUS  = '0'    " +
                                    "GROUP BY BOOK_ID, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, BOOK_DATE)) 
ORDER BY 2", cn);
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the `DAY` indicator in the `DATEADD` - it's just so much more obvious and clearer than `dd` ... (which makes it a lot more maintainable down the road!)

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, BOOK_DATE)), Sum(BOOK_COUNT)
```

DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, BOOK_DATE)) gets only the date parte of the record. you need also to group using this function.

EDITED thanks to the suggestion of @marc_s

Comment: I would prefer to use the `DAY` indicator in the `DATEADD` - it's just so much more obvious and clearer than `dd` ... (which makes it a lot more maintainable down the road!)

Answer (score 1):

Tr this. `Convert` the `BOOK_DATE` to `Date` then use it in `Group by`

```
SELECT BOOK_ID,
       CONVERT(DATE, BOOK_DATE),
       Sum(BOOK_COUNT)
FROM   BOOKS
WHERE   BOOK_ID IN (1,2,3)
       AND STATUS = 0
GROUP  BY BOOK_ID,
          CONVERT(DATE, BOOK_DATE)
```

Comment: Assuming the ?BOOK_ID` is numeric (or should be), I'd avoid adding unnecessary single quotes in the `WHERE` clause...

Answer (score 0):

To order by the second value in the result set simply add `ORDER BY 2`

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT BOOK_ID, BOOK_DATE, Sum(BOOK_COUNT) " +
                                    "FROM BOOKS " +
                                    "WHERE (BOOK_ID = '1' OR " +
                                           "BOOK_ID = '2' OR " +
                                           "BOOK_ID = '3' )  " +
                                    "AND STATUS  = '0'    " +
                                    "GROUP BY BOOK_ID, BOOK_DATE 
ORDER BY 2", cn);
```